# How is the morgan middleware able to output the statusCode of the response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, morgan

I understood middleware as functions that you chain behind your actual method-functions to output some information. Upon discovering the 'morgan' package, I realized that it retrieves the correct status code even though it should have no idea about the statusCode the next function yields after passing its req+res to the next function.

I tried to code that by myself and created a similar middleware quite easily. I found a 'statusCode' attribute, which is probably the default one."

Here is my Code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { url, method } = req;
  console.log(method, url, res.statusCode, util.getTime());
  next();
});
```

and the reaction to a delete-request:

```
above code: DELETE /user/17 200 0:51.21.226
morgan:     DELETE /user/17 404 222.601 ms - 48
```

Comment: `morgan` is express middleware that produces a function with the signature `(req, res, next)` so the status code is accessible from `res.status`, as you discovered yourself  in your own example.

Comment: but the problem is that I won't get resulting code the way morgan gets it. I only get the neverchanging default pre-function statusCode of 200, while morgan get's the actual statusCode that is send out (404 in this example).

Comment: The package source code is on GitHub, you should read it. Then check out `on-finished`.

Comment: Morgan is apparently installing an event handler that tells it when the response has been sent and it is outputting the final statusCode.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks to both of you, I'm going check the source code. Putting an event handler in-between that procedure makes definitely sense.